# ¿Cómo puedo condicionar una consulta en una condición PHP?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, mysqli

EDIT: Tengo un formulario PHP que maneja 3 Criterios un ID (cedula) un PASS (numero x) y un tercer campó "RANGO" que es una lista desplegable con meses de cada año (...diciembre 2021, enero 2022,). Como resultado se ejecuta una consulta en la BD si existe ID y PASS trae todos los datos del empleado; como son tantos datos se usa el valor de la lista desplegable para filtrar y traer solo el mes en particular.

Todo funciona ok si el ID, el PASS y el RANGO están en la BD registrados; pero si el empleado elige en "RANGO" un mes que no tiene datos de el, el resultado es una pagina en blanco pero quiero que salga una mensaje o alguna alerta de que debe elegir un Rango diferente pues no hay datos en la base de datos.

Código del resultado al que no se como ponerle la condición para que en caso de no estar el rango en la BD mostrar mensaje:

```
<?php  
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['identificacion'])) {
        header('Location: logindesp.php');
    }elseif(isset($_SESSION['identificacion'])) {
        include 'model/conexion.php';
        $sentencia = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM quincenas WHERE Cedula = '".$_SESSION['identificacion']."' AND Rango = '".$_SESSION['rango']."';");
        $empleado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        //print_r($empleado);
    }else{
        echo "Error en el sistema";
        }
    include('fechaes.php');
    $miFecha = date('d-m-Y');
    
    include 'model/closeconexion.php';

    foreach ($empleado as $dato) {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Desprendible</title>
  
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    alert("Bienvenido: <?php echo $dato->Nombre; ?> ");
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="model/CSS/paper.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="model/CSS/paper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="model/CSS/style.css">  
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/images/imagen33-1-125x171-125x171.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>@page { size: letter }</style>
</head>

<body class="letter">

  <section class="sheet padding-10mm">
    <table class="table" border="">
            <tbody >
            
            <tr>  
              <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center"><strong><h4>DESPRENDIBLE DE NOMINA</h4><a href="model/cerrar.php">X</a></strong>
              </td>
            </tr>
                
                
                <tr>  
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center"><strong><h3>DATOS DEL EMPLEADO</h3></strong>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><br>
                    <strong>NOMBRE:<br>IDENTIFICACIÓN:<br>CARGO:<br>FECHA DE INGRESO:<br>PERIODO LIQUIDADO:<br>DÍAS LABORADOS<br>CENTRO DE COSTOS:</strong></td>
                    <td colspan="3"><br><?php echo $dato->Nombre; ?><br><?php echo $dato->Cedula; ?><br><?php echo $dato->Cargo; ?><br><?php echo fechaEs ($dato->Fechaingreso); ?><br><?php echo $dato->Rango; ?><br><?php echo $dato->Dl; ?><br><?php echo $dato->Centrocosto; ?></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            <?php } ?>
          </table>
          
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué quieres decir con esto: *este ultimo es un SELECT en el formulario previo a la consulta y que esta almacenado en una variable que luego se carga aqui.*  y con esto: *Si se elige un valor en "RANGO" que no este en la BD la pagina queda en blanco pero si se elige uno que si esta, muestra todos los datos consultamos como debe ser. Creo que necesito condicionar ese campo pero no se como hacer.* ? Pulsa en [edit] y aclara mejor el problema, poniendo algún ejemplo si es posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sale la pagina en blanco porque estás poniendo la mayoría del código `HTML` dentro del `foreach` y al no devolver resultados, no carga el código que está dentro.

Prueba de esta manera... Si el array `$empleado` llega vacío (sin datos), imprimes un `tr` con el mensaje que quieras mostrar. En caso contrario (si vienen datos) muestras los `tr` que consideres necesarios, (*aunque según veo, solo son los `tr` que tienen los datos de los empleados*).

Esta no es la manera más elegante de hacerlo y obviamente hay que adaptar más código del que te propongo en el ejemplo, pero esa tarea te la dejo.

```
<!-- El código HTML previo -->
<tbody>
<?php if (empty($empleado)) { ?>
  <tr><td>no hay información registrada con los parámetros seleccionados</td></tr>
<?php } else {
  foreach ($empleado as $dato) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <br><strong>NOMBRE:
      <br>IDENTIFICACIÓN:
      <br>CARGO:
      <br>FECHA DE INGRESO:
      <br>PERIODO LIQUIDADO:
      <br>DÍAS LABORADOS
      <br>CENTRO DE COSTOS:</strong>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <br><?php echo $dato->Nombre; ?>
      <br><?php echo $dato->Cedula; ?>
      <br><?php echo $dato->Cargo; ?>
      <br><?php echo fechaEs ($dato->Fechaingreso); ?>
      <br><?php echo $dato->Rango; ?>
      <br><?php echo $dato->Dl; ?>
      <br><?php echo $dato->Centrocosto; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } 
} ?>
</tbody>
<!-- El código HTML posterior -->
```

Comment: Eres el mejor! @DjCrazy es lo que necesitaba!!